# Ensure relatively positioned element stays inside of top container

Tags: html, css

The relative and absolute positioning are great tools, but they take elements out of the flow and this leads to some restrictions in their use. I think I just encountered one of them but I'd love someone to prove me wrong.

To state it clearly: I have a div positioned relatively to its parent. The problem is, under certain conditions, this out-of-flow element can go further than the top element (e.g. the body) and add a horizontal scrollbar. Demo below:

```css
.top-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: dashed 2px red;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: dotted 1px blue;
  
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="absolute">
      absolutely
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is: **is there a way to tell CSS absolutely positioned elements should not go further left or right than the borders of `.top-container`?** Something that would behave like a sort of `max-left/max-right`.

(e.g. in my example, move the black div so that it does not go outside of the red dashed line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decided to position the element in an **exact** position - you can't say that you want it to be positioned somewhere. You can use right/left margin (or position with percentages).

Another option is to use the `overflow` option to set the scroller on the container (or to specify that if the element is getting out of it's container it should be hidden):

```css
.top-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: dashed 2px red;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: dotted 1px blue;
  
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.hidden-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.absolute {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="absolute">
      absolutely
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="top-container">
  <div class="container hidden-overflow">
    <div class="absolute">
      absolutely
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```